# Is there a way to find a picture inside another picture, using only 2D Fourier Transforms of both images?

Tags: image-processing, fourier-transform

Can Fourier Transforms of both images tell anything about "likeliness" of two pictures? If yes, how precise? Can it still work if only several pixels are different or can it tell they are same if one of images is rotated, scaled or distorted(up to some degree)?

Comment: Fourier and spatial domains are related uniquely in a one to one fashion. For most fundamental operations and operators (such as multiplication, convolution, integration (sum), differentiation (difference) ) there will be a corresponding operation/operator in Fourier domain as well. However, an operation very simple in one domain may be quite complex to implement in the reciprocal domain. Finding an image inside another is traditionally a space domain problem and forcing that into frequency domain could be an overkill, unless otherwise is proven for a particular application.

Comment: Thank you. I should look for "frequency operators" then.

Comment: no possibly you should not. What's the reason you are looking for Frequency domain techniques ? Why do not you use spatial domain ?

Comment: Because in spatial domain, I just guessed, that I have to apply more transform types to match/align shapes to start measuring their similarity compared to some magical single step in Fourier Space. For example, comparing ellipse to circle. Spatial could need to distort ellipse into a circle first and also scale the circles to have same radius. Then what to do if we don't even know what shape is this? What if its something like an apple vs car?

Comment: ok, but (afaik) there is no **magical** one step frequency domain operation that would yield the similarity between two images under all condtions. Consider looking into object recognition, pattern recognition, template matching and similar techniques... All of them are exhaustive however. No simple technique exists. Parallel processing might improve that however.

Comment: Thank you. I was after a computationally cheap yet powerful technique and only thing came into my mind was Fourier Transform for its convolution performance. If it can make full-sized Gaussian filtering on an image as quick as a traditional way but 3-sized Gaussian filter, maybe it could do something on de-filtering, as if one object was just a transformation of the other object, applying some Fourier calculation just to undo the transformation/filter. Is there a way to extract/find what "filter" was used on an image using another image(as a potentially transformed sample)?

Comment: Yes that's very true due to FFT, you can substantially decrease the execution MAC count and increase the speed of spatial convolutions by using the convolution theorem. However, object recognition is more than a convolution... But anyway, if you happen to have any large convolutions in your algorithm you can always benefit from frequency domain implementation. That's a good practice.

Comment: Do you think that taking 2 images and guessing the convolution kernel(that would make image 1 an image 2) and applying its inverse to second image, to get the first image (or something close) possible? I guess, even if its possible it would be more than 1 step? I won't ask anymore, this was last. Thank you.

Comment: sure it may be possible, but instead of a floating answer, you shall better clearly describe this **new** question in a new post ;-) so that solid answers can happen.